# Is the PS3 version of Fallout 3 unplayable?

Tags: ps3, fallout-3

I loved Fallout back in the day and I have been close to buying Fallout 3 on the PS3 for a long time.  My main hangup is that I hear it is buggy as hell and almost unplayable.  I really want to grab the GOTY edition but I'm scared.

Anyone have success with Fallout 3 on the PS3?  Has Bethseda fixed the issues in the GOTY edition?

Comment: It's also buggy as hell on the computer.  GOTY edition didn't seem to fix that at all (there is a mod which attempts to fix many of the bugs, though; but it's obviously not available for PS3..)

Comment: Good question. I was thinking about this after seeing how many mods (that included bug fixes) there were for the PC version. I'd like to see this question reworded though. Just so people know it's asking about the game's build quality and whether bugs have been fixed.

Comment: Hey Nate, did you buy it? Did you play it? How about showing one of the answers here some love by marking it correct.

Comment: I decided to say screw it.  I got Borderlands and Dragon Age: Ultimate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I put about 40 hours in to Fallout 3 on the PS3 (not the GOTY edition) - finished the main storyline, plus a bunch of side missions and random wandering. The game froze and required a hard reset of the PS3 about 3 or 4 times, and I got stuck on scenery once which required me to go back to my last save. So that's about one reload every 8 hours of play time.

While it's probably the buggiest PS3 game I've played, I wouldn't call it "unplayable", just annoying. I really enjoyed playing it and I think it's worth putting up with the bugs.

Answer (score 4):

It still has bugs, even on the PS3 GOTY edition.

The biggest problem with PS3 Fallout (and Fallout New Vegas) is that you have no access to the console (pressing the backquote "`" key) to correct any game breaking bugs that occur. The only recourse is to go back to an earlier save game.

You also do not have access to mods or cheats, which may be important to you.

My seat of the pants impression, having played both the PS3 and PC versions is that the PC version is more buggy, possibly because of my PC configuration, but any quest bugs are correctible via console commands. Furthermore after completion I can play with the console to spawn items and adjust statistics for fun and to try out different things.

Answer (score 2):

I own both the original and the GOTY versions of Fallout 3 for PS3. I've put more than 60 hours into the game and have encountered very few bugs; Certainly nothing that hampered my enjoyment of the game.

There's really no need to worry. Just buy it, play it, enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

As with any game, there are bugs. Fallout 3 is no different. I wouldn't say that it is worse then other games of similar complexity, but you do need to be careful. What's nice is that the game has a good auto-save feature that will prevent you from loosing too much time to a crash.

The biggest complaint I have is that VATS would sometimes bug out and not report the hit percentages correctly.

With New Vegas on the way, it's great fodder for a Steam sale. If you have a PC that is. If not, you can probably find it used somewhere for not a whole lot of money.